# Trouble with displaying information with Bootstrap Cards (Decks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Currently, I have my data displayed like this (and it works fine)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <% @entries.reverse.each do |entry| %>
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-title"><b><%= entry.title %></b></p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
       </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Trying to change the layout to display the data in series of three cards like here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-decks

This is how I rewrote it:

```
<div class="card-deck">
  <% @entries.each_slice(3) do |entry| %>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title"><%= entry.title %></h4>
      <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% @entries.each_slice(3) do |entry| %>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title"><%= entry.title %></h4>
      <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% @entries.each_slice(3) do |entry| %>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title"><%= entry.title %></h4>
      <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the error I receive when I try to display the page now:

```
NoMethodError in Entries#index


undefined method `title' for #<Array:0x007fa6dab11a10>
```

Why am I receiving this error?

Thank you for your help. Please let me know if this question needs further clarification and/or more information.

Further information:

```
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      category = entry.css('p.tagline > a')[0]['href']
      Entry.create!(title: title, link: link, category: category )
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: each_slice of 3 will give you array of 3 elements in entry.

Comment: You don't need to loop it thrice. just use the css mentioned at bottom of the link you shared for number of column you want and your old code is good. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#card-decks

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, would you mind making that an answer so I can see what you're talking about?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra, thank you ... just realized I missed your mention of css code at the bottom of the link ...

Comment: You need understand about `each_slice`, and grouping statements in your element is wrong. `end` need to move after `div`

Comment: @rails_id, you're right. moved `end` and displayed one group ... and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="card-columns">
   <% @entries.reverse.each do |entry| %>
     <div class="card">
       <div class="card-block">
        <p class="card-title"><b><%= entry.title %></b></p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= entry.link %></p>
       </div>
     </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
.card-columns {
  @include media-breakpoint-only(lg) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
  @include media-breakpoint-only(xl) {
    column-count: 3;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I keep comparing your code to the bootstrap's one since it's slightly different ... but it works, and it achieves what I had been trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

[each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) returns an array, and trying to access `title` or `link` on an array will return this error. To access the data, you would have to grab by index in the sliced arrays.

Comment: so I need to use `each_with_index` to fix this?

Comment: @user273072545345 You can either grab the data by index, or depending on what `@entries` is, if its an array of all the elements you want, you can loop over this with an `each` loop and possibly access `title` and `link`. What does `@entries` look like?

Comment: um ... I'm still figuring out ruby, so, not sure how to grab data by index easily anyway ... not sure what you mean by `@entries`?

Comment: `@entries` is scrapped data if that helps?

Comment: You can access data via index, i.e.) `entry[0]` using your current code, or, I believe `@entries` is an array of elements. If you try looping over it like `@entries.each do |entry|`, you can try to see if this works: `<%= entry.title %>`. This is speculation because I don't know what `@entries` looks like

Comment: hm ... I just tried your code, and the layout comes out all weird ... it doesn't display horizontally, and in three columns which is what I had been seeking for ... I do appreciate your help though! Thank you!

Comment: your code was right ... based on rails_id comment, I moved `end`, and your code worked fine. just wanted to let you know that. =)